# C++ class name collision

Tags: c++

For the following C++ code, I'm getting unexpected behavior. The behavior was verified with recent GCC, Clang and MSVC++. To trigger it, it is required to split the code among several files.

def.h

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    void call() {hook(data);}
    virtual void hook(T& arg)=0;
    T data;
};
```

foo.h

```
#pragma once
void foo();
```

foo.cc

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "def.h"

struct X : Base<int>
{
    virtual void hook(int& arg) {std::cout << "foo " << arg << std::endl;}
};


void foo()
{
    X x;
    x.data=1;
    x.call();
}
```

bar.h

```
#pragma once
void bar();
```

bar.cc

```
#include "bar.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "def.h"

struct X : Base<double>
{
    virtual void hook(double& arg) {std::cout << "bar " << arg << std::endl;}
};


void bar()
{
    X x;
    x.data=1;
    x.call();
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
foo 1
bar 1
```

Actual output:

```
bar 4.94066e-324
bar 1
```

What I expected to happen:

Inside of foo.cc, an instance of X defined within foo.cc is made and through calling call(), the implementation of hook() within foo.cc is called. Same for bar.

What actually happens:

An instance of X as defined in foo.cc is made in foo(). But when calling call, it dispatches not to hook() defined in foo.cc but to hook() defined in bar.cc. This leads to corruption, as the argument to hook is still an int, not a double.

The problem can be solved by putting definition of X within foo.cc in an other namespace than definition of X within bar.cc

**So finally the question:** There is no compiler warning about this. Neither gcc, nor clang or MSVC++ did even show a warning about this. Is that behavior valid as defined per C++ standard?

The situation seems to be a bit constructed, but it happened in a real world scenario. I was writing tests with rapidcheck, where possible actions on a unit to be tested are defined as classes. 
Most container classes have similar actions, so when writing tests for a queue and a vector, classes with names like "Clear", "Push" or "Pop" may come up several times. As these are only required locally, I've put them in directly in the sources where the tests are execute.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Comment: To avoid violating the ODR, move `X` inside an anonymous namespace (which will give them a unique but hidden name).

Comment: And yes, this is valid behavior.  The standard treats an ODR violation like a fart in an elevator, no diagnostic required.  Chapter 3.2, section 4 states so explicitly.   Can't be a compile error, this needs to be detected at link time.  But the linker is forever the weak link, they are not smart enough to detect this problem.

Comment: Doing unity/jumbo builds and/or LTO/WPO may trigger the warning.

Comment: @Acorn unity builds (which are an abomination) would give a compiler error not a linker error, as it's not even an ODR violation just an ill-formed redeclaration in a unity build. You're right that LTO enables diagnosing this, e.g. GCC will diagnose it with `-flto -Wodr`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Indeed, I should have written "a diagnostic" instead, sorry!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The program is Ill-formed, because it violates the [One-Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) by having two different definitions for class `X`. So it is not a valid C++ program. Note that the standard specifically allows compilers not to diagnose this violation. So the compilers are conforming, but the program is not valid C++ and as such has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) when executed (and thus anything can happen).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Lots of comments and all answers point into the right direction, sadly I can't mark them all as right. The definition in the C++ standard at this point seems very dangerous to me, but that's out of the scope of the question. Maybe it's required to be this way cause of how templates works in C++, but a modern language should at least complain about this.

Comment: @Johannes As I explained, the compiler (= *language*) **cannot** detect this, hence cannot complain either. The loader/linker may (and often does), though.

Comment: The linker could/should flag two vtables for the same class that don't end up looking the same / have different relocations. Your compiler is never able to see this, as it at no point sees more than one `class X`

Comment: @Walter There is no official distinction between compiler and linker. The compiler does not implement the language by itself. However, the standard is purposely worded so that a non-C++-aware linker (i.e. the platform linker, written for C and assembler originally) could be used in many cases. Particularily old linkers are still ill-suited, mostly because of implementation limits such as the maximum length of a mangled symbol.

Comment: @Johannes: And to reply to your comment; yes it's really a shame that the toolchain does not detect the issue here. However it's not that easy. In a single binary (library or executable), the linker could indeed realize the issue. However when using DLLs symbol interposition (the first matching symbol preempts future matching symbols) is a commonly used technique, so from the point of view of the loader it would be perfectly normal to see a second (different) definition. We can argue the merits of the technique, but since it's common, noone wishes to break it...

Comment: @MatthieuM. with name mangling in c++, how would the toolchain detect this issue?

Comment: @ArneVogel compilation and linking are two different steps. How exactly would a c++ compiler/linker detect this issue without compiling all source as one giant file?

Comment: @inheanyi It's simply a question of definition. If you go by the official definition, you could create a program that compiles and links in one go and still call it "compiler". I think that's what ArneVogel meant.

Comment: @iheanyi: Nope, it's irrelevant. Name mangling is about generating a unique name based on the definition. Here you have two symbols with identical names (after mangling) and the toolchain deciding to keep one without verifying that the other really is identical.

Comment: I'm quite sure Java or C# would detect this issue and give a warning about it. Their linkers can deal with that (give warning/error) cause they don't have to be C compatible and the object format is designed for the language. So C++ could theoretically but can't due to design.

Comment: @Nearoo I wasn't arguing about definition. The point is, how would this program go about solving this problem without compiling and linking **all** the files in one go which is what ArneVogel seems to suggest?

Comment: @iheanyi Again, the std. has no notion of compiler/linker (except that it defines different types of "linkage", and one footnote e.g. in [lex.name] regarding an ext. character set). The "implementation" is seen as a whole, though it is made up of compiler, linker and various libraries in practice. That said, a "smart" linker could detect simple violations of the ODR like the one given here at some extra cost, assuming the compiler emits suitable annotations. All modern object file formats are extensible btw. – this is used e.g. by [ThinLTO](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThinLTO.html).

Comment: @ArneVogel I don't see what a notion of compiler/linker has to do with it ***as I have already said twice***. The question is how such a program will detect and emit a diagnostic for this issue. That said, if you can't explain it without talking about something a compiler would do or something a "smart linker" would do, then it suggests the notion of a compiler/linker is critical to understanding what's going on here.

Comment: @iheanyi To your question _How exactly would a c++ compiler/linker detect this issue without compiling all source as one giant file?_ a) it feels like you're pointing out a contradiction that in an argument that isn't there. ArneVogel didn't say that it is possible. b) It is possible. You could for instance write a program that only keeps track of symbol names and checks if they collide, without actually compiling anything.

Comment: @Nearoo What contradiction are you talking about? I asked how existing tools would get this done from the person who said those tool can do it.

Answer (score 26):

You have two identically named, but different, classes `X` in different compilation units, rendering the program ill-formed, as there are now two symbols with the same name. Since the problem can only be detected during linking, compilers are not able (and not required) to report this.

The **only way to avoid** this sort of thing, is to put **any code** *that is not meant to be exported* (in particular all code that has not been declared in a header file) into an [**anonymous or unnamed namespace**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces):

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "def.h"

namespace {
    struct X : Base<int>
    {
        virtual void hook(int& arg) {std::cout << "foo " << arg << std::endl;}
    };
}

void foo()
{
    X x;
    x.data=1;
    x.call();
}
```

and equivalently for `bar.cc`. In fact, this is the main (sole?) purpose of unnamed namespaces.

Simply re-naming your classes (e.g. `fooX` and `barX`) may work for you in practice, but is not a stable solution, because there is no guarantee that these symbol names are not used by some obscure third-party library loaded at link- or run-time (now or at some point in the future).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looks like a generic solution for such problems. Looks to me like this should go in every c++ file that makes local definitions, just like #pragma once in the headers. Maybe the next c++ standard could make the compiler to put these things there by default :P

Comment: @Johannes I agree that placing symbols in the global namespace should be warned about (and there should be a way to suppress such a warning if one really really wants to do that). At the moment, this is just common knowledge among C++ devs, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah its hard to remember all those things. Have to switch between Python, C# and C++ every day and sometimes even have to do some Java. And even after >10 years experience with c++ you get surprised. Usually I avoid having global definitions like that at any cost, but for the unit tests... who cares...